# Android - Calendar get (Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR) dosen't work

Tags: android, get, calendar

i'm trying to get the total week of an year,
and i use this instruction:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
         now.set(Calendar.YEAR,annoInizio);
         now.set(Calendar.MONTH,11);
         now.set(Calendar.DATE, 30);

int settTotInizio = now.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

i print the varibles now and settTotinizio,
and in now the valude of WEEK_OF_YEAR is 40 but in settTotInizio is 1.

I don't understand where i do wrong.
Can someone help me?

This is my logcat:

```
I/System.out(30038): ,firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=0,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=11,WEEK_OF_YEAR=40,WEEK_OF_MONTH=1,DAY_OF_MONTH=30,DAY_OF_YEAR=275,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=0,HOUR_OF_DAY=12,MINUTE=48,SECOND=49,MILLISECOND=762,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]


I/System.out(30038): settTotInizio: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Months are zero-based so setting 11 to month field sets it to December. And 2013-12-30 is week number 1 in your locale.

Why the log prints week 40 first is because after the `set()` calls the other fields are not yet recomputed from the default current date values. If you switched the ordering of the log prints, you'd get compatible results as `get()` on a `Calendar` completes the other calendar fields.

Comment: Thanks now i've resolt! :)